# T-SQL: Why use INSERT INTO tblA SELECT .. FROM (MERGE tblA USING tblB ..)?

Tags: sql-server, merge, insert

I thought I understood the T-SQL MERGE statement, but I keep seeing INSERT statements that use MERGE as the source.  Why?  What's being accomplished here that can't be accomplished with the MERGE itself?  For example:

```
INSERT INTO tblA (col1, col2) 
SELECT colA, colB FROM (
    MERGE tblA AS dst 
    USING tblOther AS src ON src.col1 = dst.colA AND src.col2 = dst.colB 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (/* column list */)
    VALUES (/* column list */)
    WHEN MATCHED AND dst.SomeFlag = 'Y'
    AND (src.col1 + src.col2) <> (dst.colA + dst.colB)
    THEN UPDATE 
    SET tblA.FlagCol = 'N'
    OUTPUT src.*, $Action AS MergeAction
) AS mrg
WHERE MergeAction = 'update';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a history table modification. When you need to keep all previous versions of the data, updating an existing row physically consists of two different operations:

- Inserting new row with new values;
- Updating previously active row as non-active (either via flag or date range).

You can't do both in a single `MERGE` per se, because match conditions have to be unique. So, when a new version of an existing row arrives, the `MERGE` only does the update part, and the new data is inserted via the outermost query, for which the `MERGE`'s `output` clause is used as a source.

However, starting with SQL Server 2016, we now have a built-in support for this scenario in a form of [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables), so the whole thing becomes a bit easier.

Comment: Thanks, Roger, this answers my question.  I was able to confirm with a test found at https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2883/using-the-sql-server-merge-statement-to-process-type-2-slowly-changing-dimensions/.  (Too bad I didn't find that earlier.)

Comment: No worries, @EricB, you can still mark it as an answer :)